# Expectation of product of sample averages

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, expected-value

I have a bunch of iid random variables $X_i\sim q$ and I have defined other random variables $A_i = a(X_i)$ and $B_i = b(X_i)$. Then I bumped into the following expression
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N A_i\right)\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N B_i\right)\right]
&= \frac{1}{N^2}\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N A_i B_j\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N \mathbb{E}[A_i B_j]
\end{align}
$$

> What does $\mathbb{E}[A_i B_j]$ mean here?

It seems like a stupid question, but it's not clear to me what it represents. I tried to write it out as an integral but without success. I don't understand what distribution it is with respect to. Is it this?
$$
\mathbb{E}[A_i B_j] = \int\int  a(x) b(y) q(dx) q(dy).
$$
Surely, this cannot be correct, otherwise it would mean $\mathbb{E}[A_i B_j] = \mathbb{E}[A]\mathbb{E}[B]$, which would lead to
$$
\mathbb{E}[\bar{A}\bar{B}] = \mathbb{E}[A]\mathbb{E}[B],
$$
where $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$ are the sample averages above, and this cannot be true.

## Additional Details

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and a measurable space $(E, \mathcal{E})$ a random variable is a measurable function $X:\Omega\to E$. Expectations of this random variables are
$$
\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{\Omega} X(\omega) \mathbb{P}(d\omega).
$$
Given another random variable $Y$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ we know that $\mathbb{E}[XY]\neq \mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$ except when $X$ and $Y$ are independent. However, I don't see how $\mathbb{E}[XY]$ can **ever** be different from $\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$. Indeed I could define $Z(\omega, \omega') = X(\omega) Y(\omega')$ as a random variable on $(\Omega\times\Omega, \mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}\otimes \mathbb{P})$ and its expectation would be defined as
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Z] 
&= \int_{\Omega\times\Omega} Z(\omega, \omega') \mathbb{P}(d\omega)\mathbb{P}(d\omega') \\
&= \int_\Omega \int_\Omega X(\omega) Y(\omega') \mathbb{P}(d\omega)\mathbb{P}(d\omega') \\
&= \left[\int_\Omega X(\omega) \mathbb{P}(d\omega)\right]\left[\int_\Omega Y(\omega') \mathbb{P}(d\omega')\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y].
\end{align}
$$
Now, in the context of my main question, what would $\mathbb{E}[A_i B_j]$ be? I want to write it down as an integral but I am struggling to do so. Especially because $a(X_i)$ and $b(X_i)$ are functions of the same underlying random variables.

Comment: Because I find your question baffling -- "what does it represent?" seems self-evident -- allow me to simplify the notation.  Let $U$ stand for the random variable $A_i$ and $V$ stand for $B_j.$ You are asking "what does $E[UV]$ mean?"  If that's not sufficiently clear, let $W$ stand for the random variable $UV$.  Your question is "what does $E[W]$ mean"?  Are you looking for a definition, some kind of interpretation, or something else??

Comment: @whuber You are right, the question is unclear. I've added details

Comment: Re the edits: again, simplifying the notation helps. Since $$E[W]=\int_{\Omega}W(\omega)\mathbb P(\mathrm d\omega),$$ substitution $W=A_iB_j$ and the definition $(A_iB_j)(\omega)=A_i(\omega)B_j(\omega)$ gives $$E[A_iB_j]=\int_{\Omega}A_i(\omega)B_j(\omega)\mathbb P(\mathrm d\omega).$$ For examples of non-independent random variables you need look no further than spaces $\Omega$ with two elements.

Comment: @whuber I'm confused, why is the sample space of $W$ simply $\Omega$ and not $\Omega\times\Omega$?

Comment: I don't see why your random variable $Z(\omega, \omega^\prime) = X(\omega)Y(\omega^\prime)$ is equivalent to a random variable $Z(\omega) = X(\omega)Y(\omega)$. These two random variables aren't even on the same probability space. And the way you have constructed the product space, it's bound to be that any two random variables $X$ and $Y$ will factor in expectation because the measure you have defined on the product space is a product measure! Product measures are the underlying measure theoretic basis for independence.

Comment: @whuber and Something is wrong. In my example $X_i$ is just notation for $X(\omega_i)$ where $\omega_i\in\Omega$. I don't see how this fits with the expectation of $A_i B_j$.

By "just" notation I mean that when we write $X_1, \ldots, X_N \sim q$ basically we grab outcomes $\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_N$ independently from $\Omega$ and we construct $X_i = X(\omega_i)$. In the expression above, however, it is unclear exactly what $\mathbb{E}[A_i B_j]$ means. The expectation is taken with respect to a **function** but here $A_i$ and $B_j$ are not functions anymore, they are their evaluation

Comment: Basically $\bar{A}\in E$ and it is defined as
$$
\bar{A} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N a(X(\omega_i))
$$
where $X:\Omega\to E$ and $\omega_i\in\Omega$ are sampled independently from $\Omega$, meaning that $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_N\}) = \mathbb{P}(\omega_1)\times\cdots\times\mathbb{P}(\omega_N)$. Therefore $A_i$ cannot possibly be a function (and hence it cannot be a random variable!)
$$\quad$$
Unless what we mean is that we have $N$ functions $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ each one of these functions having the same distribution $\mathbb{P}\circ X_i^{-1}(A) = \mathbb{P}\circ X_j^{-1}(A)$

Comment: In this second scenario, then $\bar{A}$ is still a function on $\Omega$, defined as
$$
\bar{A}(\omega) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N a(X_i(\omega))
$$
and if we assume $\bar{A}\bar{B}$ is also a function on $\Omega$ then 
$$
\mathbb{E}[\bar{A}\bar{B}] = \int \bar{A}(\omega)\bar{B}(\omega) \mathbb{P}(d\omega) = \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N \int a(X_i(\omega)) b(X_j(\omega)) \mathbb{P}(d\omega)
$$
but **importantly** I cannot use the change of variables formula! @whuber

Comment: You appear to be confusing yourself by posing a trivial question within a complicated framework.  It therefore might help to simplify your problem as much as you can to help us identify what difficulty you need addressed.

Comment: @whuber I am really stuck. I guess the real difficulty I need to address is how to define the integral $\mathbb{E}[A_i B_j]$. I don't believe it is the same as the one you've written, this is not the same as $\mathbb{E}[XY]$ for two variables $X$ and $Y$. If you know how to write it down, do let me know, it would be very helpful. It is clear how it is written in terms of $\mathbb{P}$ but the thing is that we hardly ever work with that probability measure. Instead, I want to write it in terms of the distributions of the random variables involved

Comment: Okay, you don't believe what I've written (even though it is rigorously correct and I have provided the justification), so I'm not able to help.  I recommend that you consult a textbook that discusses expectation from this perspective.

Comment: @whuber I do believe what you have written. I do believe that
$$
\mathbb{E}[XY] = \int_\Omega X(\omega) Y(\omega) \mathbb{P}(d\omega).
$$
But I don't believe that $\mathbb{E}[A_i B_j]$ is of the same form. I believe that in the first display of my answer, there is a conflict of notation. The question in my answer reduces to this really: What are the indeces $i$ and $j$ inside the expectation?

Comment: In that case there's a difference of interpretation.  I think it's due to the complex circumstances of the notation.  I'm simply telling you how expressions like $E[A_iB_j]$ are always intended to be interpreted.  There's no conflict of notation, but I suspect the *algebraic manipulations,* which include sums, products, and means, might be confusing the issue, especially if you are thinking of those as some kind of "expectations" in their own right.

Comment: @whuber Okay I see. So then if $\mathbb{E}[A_i B_j]$ is of the same form as $\mathbb{E}[XY]$, how should one interpret the indeces $i$ and $j$? I have defined $A_i = a(X_i)$ and $B_i = b(X_i)$ so in theory one should have
$$
\mathbb{E}[A_i B_j] = \mathbb{E}[a\circ X_i b\circ B_j] = \int_\Omega a(X_i(\omega)) b(X_j(\omega)) \mathbb{P}(d\omega)
$$
but this does not seem to involve the joint distribution of the variables.

Comment: Again, *it's just (really simple) algebra.*  You have a collection of $2N$ random variables whose products are laid out in an $N\times N$ array.  All expectations are integrals over $\Omega$ and all sums *etc.* are just operations on the entries in this array.

Comment: Ah! Maybe I found how to do this. Define
$$
\bar{X}_{ij}:\Omega\to E\times E \qquad \text{ as} \qquad \bar{X}_{ij}(\omega) = (X_i(\omega), X_j(\omega))
$$
and 
$$
\bar{c}:E\times E \to E \qquad \text{as} \qquad \bar{c}(x, y) = a(x) b(y).
$$
Then one can write
$$
\mathbb{E}[A_i B_j] = \int_{\Omega} \bar{c}\circ\bar{X}_{ij}(\omega) \mathbb{P}(d\omega)
$$
and using the change of variables formula
$$
\mathbb{E}[A_i B_j] = \int_{E\times E} \bar{c}(x, y) P\circ \bar{X}^{-1}(dx \times dy)
$$
or
$$
\mathbb{E}[A_i B_j] = \int_{E\times E} a(x) b(y) P_{X_i X_j}(dx, dy)
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Even in very advanced mathematics it helps to study simple examples.**  Part of the art of reading and learning mathematics is to construct such examples for yourself.  This answer illustrates the process.

---

Let's consider the *simplest non-trivial possible situation*, where the probability space $\Omega = \{\omega_1, \omega_2\}$ has just two elements.  We will suppose every subset of $\Omega$ is an event, which enables us to specify any probability distribution in terms of the probabilities $\pi_i = \mathbb P(\{\omega_i\})$ (with $\pi_1+\pi_2=1,$ of course).

To be concrete, let $A:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be the random variable $A(\omega_1) = 0$ and $A(\omega_2) = 4;$ and let $B$ be the random variable $B(\omega_1) = 2$ and $B(\omega_2) = 0.$  (I chose these numbers to make the arithmetic simple, especially when working with the uniform distribution $\pi_1=\pi_2=1/2.$)

We can present this information about the random variables $A$ and $B$ conveniently as a table of probabilities and values of the random variables:

$$\begin{array}{cc|cc}
\omega & \mathbb P & A & B\\
\hline
\omega_1 &\pi_1 & 0 & 2\\
\omega_2 & \pi_2 & 4 & 0
\end{array}$$

**To construct *iid* variables we need $N$ separate copies of this probability space.**  The simplest way, with $N=2,$ is to work in the product space $\Omega\times \Omega.$  The definitions tell us all the probabilities and the values of the random variables, so I will just summarize the results here, writing $(\omega,\eta)$ for a generic element of $\Omega\times \Omega.$  $A_1$ is the random variable defined by

$$A_1(\omega,\eta) = A(\omega)$$

while $A_2$ is the random variable

$$A_2(\omega,\eta) = A(\eta),$$

and likewise for the $B_i.$

$$\begin{array}{ccc|rrrr}
\omega & \eta & \mathbb P & A_1 & A_2 & B_1 & B_2\\
\hline
\omega_1 & \omega_1 & \pi_1^2 &  0 & 0 & 2 & 2\\
\omega_1 & \omega_2 & \pi_1\pi_2 &  0 & 4 & 2 & 0\\
\omega_2 & \omega_1 & \pi_2\pi_1 &  4 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
\omega_2 & \omega_2 & \pi_2^2 &  4 & 4 & 0 & 0
\end{array}$$

**There's nothing new here: this is the standard product construction for creating *iid* variables.**  If you're unconvinced, verify that $(A_1,A_2)$ are independent and $(B_1,B_2)$ are independent.

**The question concerns functions of these random variables.**  The left hand side of the equation in the question expands to

$$E\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N A_i\right] = E\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(A_1+A_2\right)\right].$$

It is convenient to denote this $\bar A,$ as in the question.  $\bar B$ is similarly defined.  Let's expand the preceding table to include these quantities as well as their product, $\bar A \bar B = (\sum A_i \sum B_j)/N^2.$  Looking ahead to the right hand side of the equation, I will also include the products $A_iB_j:$

$$\begin{array}{ccc|rrrr:cccccc:c}
\omega & \eta & \mathbb P & A_1 & A_2 & B_1 & B_2 & A_1B_1 & A_1B_2 & A_2B_1 & A_2B_2 & \bar A & \bar B & \bar A \bar B\\
\hline
\omega_1 & \omega_1 & \pi_1^2 &  0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\omega_1 & \omega_2 & \pi_1\pi_2 &  0 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 2\\
\omega_2 & \omega_1 & \pi_2\pi_1 &  4 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 2\\
\omega_2 & \omega_2 & \pi_2^2 &  4 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0
\end{array}$$

*There is nothing probabilistic about these calculations.*  They are carried out separately on each row and are completely deterministic.

The integrals are just sums of values times their probabilities, as always:

$$\begin{aligned}
E[\bar A\bar B] &= \iint_{\Omega\times \Omega} \bar A(\omega,\eta)\bar B(\omega,\eta)\mathbb (\mathbb P\otimes\mathbb P)(\mathrm d(\omega,\eta))\\
& = \pi_1^2(0) + \pi_1\pi_2(2) + \pi_2\pi_1(2) + \pi_2^2(0) = 2\pi_1\pi_2. 
\end{aligned}\tag{*}$$

That's the left hand side of the equation in the question.  The right hand side is a combination of four expectations.  They are worked out in the same way from the table, by multiplying suitable columns by their probabilities and summing:

$$\begin{aligned}
E[A_1B_1] &= \pi_1^2(0) + \pi_2\pi_1(0) + \pi_1\pi_2(0) + \pi_2^2(0) &= 0\\
E[A_1B_2] &= \cdots &= \pi_2\pi_1(8)\\
E[A_2B_1] &= \cdots &= \pi_1\pi_2(8)\\
E[A_2B_2] &= \cdots &= 0.
\end{aligned}$$

Consequently -- still just doing simple algebra,

$$\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_i\sum_j E[A_iB_j] = \frac{1}{4}\left(0 + \pi_2\pi_1(8) + \pi_1\pi_2(8) + 0)\right) = 2\pi_1\pi_2,$$

agreeing with $(*)$ and demonstrating the equation in this case.

---

Finally, compute $E[\bar A] = 4\pi_2^2 + 4\pi_1\pi_2$ and $E[\bar B] = 2\pi_1\pi_2.$  For most values of $\pi_1$ the product of these expectations does not equal $E[\bar A\bar B] = 2\pi_1\pi_2:$ that is because $A$ and $B$ are not independent.  (Indeed, $B = (4-A)/2$ exhibits this dependence explicitly.)

Comment: This is really great, thank you so much for putting in the effort of doing this. I really appreciate it.